# How to enable keyboard when yoga pad 2 is folded as a tablet?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, tablet

I have a Yoga Pad 2 Pro, and when I'm using it's HDMI port to output to a larger display, I don't really have any usage for the laptop's display, so I thought I could turn the display off and fold it up so it would be like a keyboard, but this makes the keyboard turn off.  How can I disable this feature?

Comment: @biggles5107 because, from what I can gather, this feature wasn't present in ubuntu 12 and needed a workaround.

Comment: Does that mean you have found a solution?

Comment: @FranzReprimand No, i gave up

Answer (score 1):

You must disable the HID Sensor collection under Device Manager --> Sensors for this to work. I'm not sure exactly what this device controls but so far I've found that it does control the keyboard on/off when in tablet mode. So no, this is not hardware based.

Comment: Where do I find this device manager?

Answer (score 0):

On Yoga 520 just put a strong magnet above the F3 (volume +) tangent and you can use keyboard while folded 360.

just find the sweet spot, might take some try tho.
but you'll notice the switch when magnet is near F3.
you also need a mouse connected to open and click in field to test
your typing, like google search field.

have fun

Answer (score 0):

On a Thinkpad Yoga (S1 Yoga 12) I was able to resolve this by disabling "Sensor Monitoring Service" using the "Services" application. Note that this will affect other sensors, such as adaptive brightness monitoring.